# Remove DOM element everytime (after fetching)

Tags: javascript, dom, setinterval

Hi I am trying to build a game dashboard with vanilla JavaScript. The problem is, It is always showing the previous element. I use `setInterval` for refreshing.

Here is an example

**JavaScript**

```
function fetching() {
...
  .then(data => {
     dataApply(data)
  })
...
}


function dataApply(data) {
  data.EneymyHealth.forEach(monster => {
    if (monster.isAlive) {                    //Check monster alive
     const p = document.createElement('p');   //Create <p> element
     p.innerHTML = monster.HP;                //Add monster's HP into <p>
     enemyWrapper.appendChild(p);             //Attach <p> into <div id="wrapper">
   }
 })
}

setInterval(fetching, 1000);
```

But when I inspected by web browser. The result was weird.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  ....
  <p>2000</p>
  <p>2000</p>
  <p>2000</p>
  ....
</div>
```

It is looped by `setInterval` but the `<p>` element does not remove. It still shows a previous one.

How can I remove it ? Thank you for your answer.

*Note*

1. I want to build a real-time monster dashboard. So, I think `setInterval` is a best choice for real-time HP monster. (It is synced with third party game)

Comment: are you sure that the value of **monster.HP** is different for each item ?
Please paste the content of **data.EneymyHealth**

Comment: I would change `p.innerHTML = monster.HP;` to `p.textContent = moster.HP; enemyWrapper.innerHTML = ''`. `.textContent` to prevent HTML parse errors. `enemyWrapper.innerHTML = ''` to clear out the `enemyWrapper` Element, without testing against the children. Of course, I have to ask why it's in an interval?

Comment: @PatrissolKenfack I am sure that the monster.HP does not duplicate. I just show you an example of 1 monster (HP) in game. //// @StackSlave I use setInterval for a real-time update. (I synchronize with third party game.) If you have any method, please suggest me. Also, your answer `enemyWrapper.innerHTML = ''` works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not removing enemy before running the loop

What you have to do is

```
enemyWrapper.querySelectorAll('.enemy').forEach((currEnemy) {
    currEnemy.remove();
});
data.EneymyHealth.forEach(monster => {
    if (monster.isAlive) {                    //Check monster alive
       const p = document.createElement('p');   //Create <p> element
       p.classList.add('enemy')
       p.innerHTML = monster.HP;                //Add monster's HP into <p>
       enemyWrapper.appendChild(p);             //Attach <p> into <div id="wrapper">
    }
})
```

What I did is, I add class enemy to all enemies, and before adding it to DOM removed all enemies, so that only alive enemies can be re rendered in DOM

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Thanks all.

I have to clear before starting append a new one.

```
enemyWrapper.innerHTML = '';            //Clear innerHTML
data.EneymyHealth.forEach(monster => {   //Mapping array into DOM
    ....
)
```